# c++ getting result value from void function

Tags: c++, void

```
void dtob(int n) {
    if(n/2!=0){
        dtob(n/2);
    }
    return n%2;
}
```

so what I want to do here is get an int from `int main()` and return its binary value but I don't know how to return the value from `void dtob`. What do I have to use instead of `return`?

Comment: Probably pass in an empty string and keep appending to it.

Comment: Obvious question, but, does it have to be `void`?

Comment: Remember: You're not only returning a value to `main`, but also to yourself. It's a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Change `void` to `int` and use returned value.

<del>and return `n%2` is `0` so use `return 0`.</del>

Comment: @M.M it's true, fixed